# subclassed parse user returns nil when accessing a class property

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Looks like my PFUser subclass returns a PFUser and I get nil when trying to access my subclass properties

FEUser.h

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface FEUser : PFUser<PFSubclassing>
@property (retain) PFGeoPoint *location;
@property (retain) NSString *name;
+ (FEUser *)currentUser;
@end
```

FEUser.m

```
#import "FEUser.h"

@implementation FEUser
@dynamic name;
@dynamic location;

+ (FEUser *)currentUser {
    return (FEUser *) [PFUser currentUser];
}
@end
```

The problem

```
[FEUser currentUser].name; //returns nil
```

Comment: Casting a reference to a different class doesn't actually change the  class of the object it points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to sign the user out and sign back in in the simulator to get the properties working.  Parse must have cached the currentUser.